# VLC 2.1.5 (all versions and 2.2.0) plays only audio not video

Tags: video, vlc

My 27" iMac on Yosemite, presents the same symptoms described in  *'VLC in Mac does not show video window 2'*. I tried all the actions available ie reinstalling, trashing preferences, the solutions proposed in the above mentioned questions etc but the result is the same: for all formats on file open or on double click, the application opens a new video window who closes immediately and the clip plays only the audio track.
The same clips play OK on QT, RealPlayer, MPlayer etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced something similar with VLC. Typically, I play vids in full screen on my second display connected to my MacBook. When I am not connected to the external display and I play a vid, VLC seems to want to still play in this dual display mode. So it's like it's playing on a ghost second display.

If this is your situation, the easiest solution is to **simply press 'Escape'.** That pulls the vid out of full screen mode (on the ghost second monitor) and displays it in windowed mode.

From there you should be good.

(P.S. *I just wrote this same thing in another similar VLC post earlier today... Must be something in the air.*)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is trivial but check your settings in VLC preferences for Enable Video.

[image: video]